# Robot or confused person?

Tags: discussion

I've just come across [this unregistered user](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/13155/mritunjay?tab=activity) answering [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18730/seo-optimizing-blogger-blogspots) with

"essie Paul speaks about Crowdsourcing Company and its benefits. project2. Motivate the Indian ... Anthem India will be eventually a group of companies focusin... $178 .using crowdsourcing turned out be advantageous for these clients"

Is it just me or does this look like a robot post? Flagged the post anyway, does this kind of thing show up often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source of the post you see a link that isn't shown in the final post (due to the restrictions on 1 rep users I suspect). This is pure spam, likely posted by a person. The anti-robot measures of SE were improved a while ago and I haven't seen any large-scale spam attacks since then.

Comment: Good find. I saw something like this a few weeks back only the link was hidden in a question.